# SR-IOV with VFIO driver

Tags: linux, drivers, virtual-machine, virtualization

I'm trying to enable SR-IOV ports (VF) when the Physical ports (PF) is running VFIO-PCI driver.

I've enabled this patch to the VFIO driver in order to create VF on the Physical port:
https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10103353/

The problem is that once to bind VFIO driver to the created VF I expect to see new device node /dev/vfio/X with the relevant IOMMU group, In this case I can't connect the VF to VM using Libvirt which is looking for this file.

The sequence I did is:

## Create 4 VF on the PF

echo '4' > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:06:00.0/sriov_numvfs

## Unbind the 4 VF from the default driver

echo "0000:06:10.0" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbevf/unbind
echo "0000:06:10.2" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbevf/unbind
echo "0000:06:10.4" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbevf/unbind
echo "0000:06:10.6" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ixgbevf/unbind

## Bind the VF to VFIO-PCI driver

echo "8086 15c5" > /sys/bus/pci/drivers/vfio-pci/new_id

After the last command I expect to see new /dev/vfio/X file for each VF.
I can see that each VF is in different IOMMU group.

What I'm missing here ? Is there any other option to use SR-IOV with VFIO driver ?

Regards,
Amir.